# Save current position without modifying the document layout

Tags: tikz-pgf, layout, tikzmark, zref

### Description

I would like to add code to the preamble of a document such that I am able to identify and store the vertical position of an environment without modifying the layout.

That is to say I require the rendered document to be identical whether my code is present or not.

### What I have tried

#### MWE

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{zref-savepos}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newcounter{i}
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{equation}{
    \stepcounter{i}%
    \zsaveposy{start-\thei}%
}%
\begin{document}
    \begin{equation}
        x = \frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a}
    \end{equation}
    \begin{equation}
        e = mc^2
    \end{equation}
    \begin{align}
        y &= mx + b \\
        a &= \frac{y - b}{x}
    \end{align}
\end{document}
```

### Issue

Using `\zsaveposy{}`, `\pdfsavepos{}`, `\tikzmark{}`, and `\tikzmarknode{}` all change the layout when they are used prior to beginning an equation environment.

#### Illustration of the issue:

An overlay of the rendered document, with and without the use of the `\zsaveposy{}` command, demonstrating the resulting change to the layout:
[image: Overlay of the rendered document with and without \zsaveposy{}]

### Desired result

The ability to store the y-position in the document at the start and end of every environment to be used during shipout, without altering the original page layout.

Comment: What do you want to do with the information during shipout exactly?

Comment: You have a spurious space at the start, but I don't think that's relevant. How did you generate the image exactly? Because I can't see any difference in the positioning with or without your code.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the second `\pdfsavepos` (before `$$e=mc^2$$`) is inserted in horizontal mode just after the first equation. The horizontal mode is opened by internal `\noindent`. If the `\pdfsavepos` isn't here then the following equation closes this horizontal mode immediately without any material in the horizontal list, so the paragraph line before `$$e=mc^2$$` isn't created. But if the `\pdfsavepos` is here then the paragraph line is created here, so there is one more `\hbox` in the main vertical list.

I suggest to close horizontal mode, then insert `\pdfsavepos` and then open horizontal mode again with `\noindent` if we are in the horizontal mode. But this will not work correctly when there is a long sentence just before the `equation`, because display mode gets incorrect value of `\predisplaysize` and `\above/below/displayshortskip` is used instead correct `\above/below/dipslayskip`. But it depends on what cases you want to use this. Maybe you don't want to have any sentences just before equations.

```
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{equation}{
    \stepcounter{i}%
    \ifhmode \par \zsaveposy{start-\thei}\noindent
    \else \zsaveposy{start-\thei}
    \fi
}%
```